# VBA nested Loop flow control

Tags: vba, loops, excel, nested

I will be brief and stick to what I know. This code for the most part works as it should. The only issue is in the iteration of the x and z loop. these to loops should set the range and yLABEL for the Y loop. 
I can get through a set and come up with the correct range after that things go bonkers. I know some of it has to do with not breaking out of x to set z and then back to x update the range.

It should work  z is found then x. the range between them is set for y. then next x but y stays then rang between y and x is set for y.. so on and so forth kinda like a slinky down the stairs. or a slide rule depending on how I set the loops either way I end up all over the place after a couple iterations.

I have done a few things but each time I break out of x  to set z , X restarts at the top of the range. At least that's what I think I am seeing. In the example sheet i have since changed the way the way the offset works with the loop but the idea is still the same. I have goto statements at this time i was going to try figuring out conditional switches after the loops were working.  Any help direction or advice is appreciated.

[image: Example of worksheets]

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse()

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

            Dim strPath As String, strPathused As String
            strPath = "C:\clerk plan2"

            Dim objfso As FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder, objfile As Object

            Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objfso.GetFolder(strPath)

    'Loop through objWorkBooks
For Each objfile In objFolder.Files

        If objfso.GetExtensionName(objfile.Path) = "xlsx" Then

            Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
            Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objfile.Path)

            ' Set path for move to at end of script
            strPathused = "C:\prodplan\used\" & objWorkbook.Name
            objWorkbook.Worksheets("inbound transfer sheet").Activate
            objWorkbook.Worksheets("inbound transfer sheet").Cells.UnMerge

            'Range management WB
            Dim SRCwb As Worksheet, SRCrange1 As Range, SRCrange2 As Range, lastrow As Range

            Set SRCwb = objWorkbook.Worksheets("inbound transfer sheet")
            Set SRCrange1 = SRCwb.Range("g3:g150")
            Set SRCrange2 = SRCwb.Range("a1:a150")


            Dim DSTws As Worksheet
            Set DSTws = Workbooks("clerkplan2.xlsm").Worksheets("transfer")


            Dim STR1 As String, STR2 As String, xVAL As String, zVAL As String, xSTR As String, zSTR As String

            STR1 = "INBOUND TRANS"
            STR2 = "INBOUND CA TRANS"

            Dim x As Variant, z As Variant, y As Variant, zxRANGE As Range
 For Each z In SRCrange2
        zSTR = Mid(z, 1, 16)
        If zSTR <> STR2 Then GoTo zNEXT
         If zSTR = STR2 Then
            zVAL = z
        End If

For Each x In SRCrange2
        xSTR = Mid(x, 1, 13)
        If xSTR <> STR1 Then GoTo xNEXT
         If xSTR = STR1 Then
            xVAL = x
       End If

           Dim yLABEL As String

        If xVAL = x And zVAL = z Then
         If x.Row > z.Row Then
            Set zxRANGE = SRCwb.Range(x.Offset(1, 0).Address & " : " & z.Offset(-1, 0).Address)
            yLABEL = z.Value
       Else
            Set zxRANGE = SRCwb.Range(z.Offset(-1, 0).Address & " : " & x.Offset(1, 0).Address)
            yLABEL = x.Value
         End If
       End If
                                        MsgBox zxRANGE.Address ' DEBUG
For Each y In zxRANGE


        If y.Offset(0, 6) = "Temp" Or y.Offset(0, 14) = "Begin Time" Or y.Offset(0, 15) = "End Time" Or _
            Len(y.Offset(0, 6)) = 0 Or Len(y.Offset(0, 14)) = 0 Or Len(y.Offset(0, 15)) = "0" Then yNEXT


            Set lastrow = Workbooks("clerkplan2.xlsm").Worksheets("transfer").Range("c" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            y.Offset(0, 6).Copy
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=True, Transpose:=False
            DSTws.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = objWorkbook.Name
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = yLABEL

            objWorkbook.Activate
            y.Offset(0, 14).Copy
            Set lastrow = Workbooks("clerkplan2.xlsm").Worksheets("transfer").Range("d" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=True, Transpose:=False

            objWorkbook.Activate
            y.Offset(0, 15).Copy
            Set lastrow = Workbooks("clerkplan2.xlsm").Worksheets("transfer").Range("e" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=True, Transpose:=False

yNEXT:
    Next y
xNEXT:
    Next x
zNEXT:
    Next z

            strPathused = "C:\clerk plan2\used\" & objWorkbook.Name


            objWorkbook.Close False
                                'Move proccesed file to new Dir

                    Dim OldFilePath As String
                    Dim NewFilePath As String

                OldFilePath = objfile 'original file location
                NewFilePath = strPathused ' new file location
                Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file




        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the same range when you say:

`For Each z In SRCrange2` and `For Each x In SRCrange2`

Does this help, or at least get you on the right track?

```
For Each z In SRCrange2

        zSTR = Mid(z, 1, 16)
        xSTR = Mid(x, 1, 13)

        If zSTR <> STR2 AND xSTR <> STR1 Then GoTo zNEXT

        If zSTR = STR2 Then zVAL = z
        If xSTR = STR1 Then xVAL = x

        ... [rest of code] ...

zNext:
Next z
```

Comment: Scott thank you for the reply I am looking through your suggestion . Its most likely my thick head but I'm not seeing how I can set two variables with one loop. Again thanks for the reply I will keep playing with your suggestion and see if a light pops on.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying more clearly now. For every `Z` your code starts at the beginning of `srcRange2` at the `For each X ...` each time. If you want X to start at the X you left off with at the last Z loop, you'll need to track it somehow. Perhaps you can put the last X row used in variable and then use the `Cells` method to tell the `X` where to start from, like `For Each X in srcRange2.Cells(myRow,1)`

Comment: Scott thanks again I'm playing with something like that right now.I will post if it works. If it doesn't I may have to replace my laptops screen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume looping through the files isn't a problem, so I'm not going to address that.  If I was going to take your source data and turn it into your processed data, I would do it like this

```
Sub Parse()

    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim bStartGroup As Boolean
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim sDateCycle As String
    Dim rNext As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A150")
    Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        'only change sDateCycle when a new group starts
        If StartsGroup(rCell.Value) Then
            sDateCycle = rCell.Value
        Else 'not the start of a group, so process the data
            'don't copy blanks or headers
            If IsData(rCell.Value) Then
                'find the next blank cell
                Set rNext = shDest.Cells(shDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'write the date cycle
                rNext.Value = sDateCycle
                'write the workbook name
                rNext.Offset(0, 1).Value = rRng.Parent.Parent.Name
                'write the time in, time out, and smelly
                rCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Copy rNext.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub

Function StartsGroup(ByVal sValue As String) As Boolean

    'You need to write this funciton to return True when the cell you're on starts a new date cycle
    'I wrote it to check if everything after the last space is a date
    'Your logic may be different (and easier)

    Dim lSpace As Long

    lSpace = InStrRev(sValue, Space(1))

    If lSpace > 0 Then
        StartsGroup = IsDate(Mid(sValue, lSpace + 1, Len(sValue)))
    End If

End Function

Function IsData(ByVal sValue As String) As Boolean

    'You need to write this function to return True when the cell your on should be copied
    'I wrote it to not copy blanks or headers
    'Your logic will likely be different

    IsData = Len(sValue) > 0 And sValue <> "clerks"

End Function
```

You'll have some major changes to incorporate this into your loop that loops through the files, but it may give you some ideas.  The basic flow is that if the cell I'm on starts a group, I store its value in sDateCycle.  If it doesn't start a group, then I make sure it's valid data, and if so, write it to shDest.

Note that I made my shDest to be a new worksheet in the same workbook.  You'll just need to change the Set shDest = ... line to point to the sheet you want to work write to.

I think putting StartsGroup and IsData into separate functions will make things simpler.  You don't have to pass rCell.Value into those functions, however.  If you want to check, say, Column G or more than one column, you can pass rCell (and change the function parameter to ByRef rCell as Range instead of ByVal sValue As String).  Then in the function you could say

```
StartsGroup =  rCell.Value = "This" and rCell.Offset(0,10).Value = "That"
```

or whatever your logic is.  Whatever you need to do in those functions, just think of it in terms of the cell you're on so you only have to loop once.  Maybe the cell two rows down and one to the right has to be a certain value to identify the start of a group, for instance.